# How do directories impact the page URL in hugo?

Tags: routes, hugo

I'm very new to hugo and just generated a new project. And ran `hugo new lessons/first.md` and added a "Hello World" to it. When I run `hugo server` it starts hosting on http://localhost:1313/, but I don't know how I can access the `lessons/first` page. When I go to `http://localhost:1313/lessons/first` I get a `This is not the page you were looking for` error.

Answer (score 2):

I would run `hugo` without parameters so that hugo creates the entire web page in the `/public`-folder. After a look into the `public`-folder you should be able to see how the path to your previously created subpage (`lessons/first`) is. Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably happening because of `draft: true` in the frontmatter of first.md, try deleting that line & run `hugo server`.